# Как упростить код

Tags: python

Добрый день, я самостоятельно изучаю пайтон. Вот программа,водишь четыре числа
с одинаковым диапазоном значений и выводится сообщение.

Как я понимаю, программирование это поиск зависимостей. Вот я вижу зависимость
от нуля до 2 у всех переменных. Но как записать этот код проще, пока понять не могу. Или упростить его уже нельзя?

Ну и второй вопрос. Знаю, вроде как здесь в правилах, запрещают философские вопросы, но я попытаюсь сформулировать конкретней.

Я почитал о синтаксисе языка, об основных конструкциях, но сейчас сталкиваюсь с проблемой,что могу описать блок-схему на листочке своими словами,
а вот как сделать ее программно не всегда сразу схватываю. Может на эту тему есть литература? или это уже первый звоночек, что 
программирование это не мое? Вообщем, если кто то сталкивался с таким в обучении, напишите пару слов.

```
my_numbers = input("Введите числа:").split(" ")
one_number = int(my_numbers[0])
two_number = int(my_numbers[1])
three_number = int(my_numbers[2])
four_number = int(my_numbers[3])

if one_number>=0 and one_number <=2:
    print("БЕЛЫЙ")
if two_number >=0 and two_number <=2:
    print("Маленький")
if three_number>=0 and three_number <=2:
    print("Хороший")
if four_number >= 0 and four_number <= 2:
    print("Вредный")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой вариант решения для Python 3. *Но не сказал бы, что он - проще для понимания*.

```
words = [
    "БЕЛЫЙ",
    "Маленький",
    "Хороший",
    "Вредный",
]
wordlist = {
    int(k) or -99: words.pop(0) if words.__len__() else '' for k in input('Введите числа:\t').split()
}  # -99 - на случай если будет введено меньше 4-х чисел
for num, word in wordlist.items():
    if num in range(-1, 3):  # от 0 до 2 включительно, только целочисленные с шагом 1
        print(word)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
words = [
    "БЕЛЫЙ",
    "Маленький",
    "Хороший",
    "Вредный",
]
wordlist = {
    int(k) or -99: words.pop(0) if words.__len__() else '' for k in input('Введите числа:\t').split()
}  # -99 - на случай если будет введено меньше 4-х чисел
for num, word in wordlist.items():
    if num in range(-1, 3):  # от 0 до 2 включительно, только целочисленные с шагом 1
        print(word)
</script>
```

Comment: Ещё было бы неплохо отлавливать ошибку при преобразовании к целочисленному типу, на случай если введено не число.

Comment: и если будет больше чем 4 значение то тоже будет ошибка

Comment: @Twiss, исправил, но читать стало сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
my_numbers = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", input("Введите числа:"))
# my_numbers = input("Введите числа:").split(" ") # если числа > 10
items = ["Белый", "Маленький", "Хороший", "Вредный"]

for i in range(len(items)):
    if int(my_numbers[i]) <= 2:
        print(items[i])
```

---

проверка

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import re
my_numbers = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", input("Введите числа:"))
items = ["Белый", "Маленький", "Хороший", "Вредный"]

for i in range(len(items)):
    if int(my_numbers[i]) <= 2:
        print(items[i])


</script></body>
```

```
Введите числа:5123
Маленький
Хороший
```

Comment: Если число больше 10, то каждая цифра воспринимается как отдельное число.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю python, но мне кажется логика примерно такая:

```
my_numbers = input("Введите числа:").split(" ")

words = ["БЕЛЫЙ", "Маленький", "Хороший", "Вредный"]

i = 0
while i < len(my_numbers):
    n = int(my_numbers[i])
    if (n >= 0 and n <= 2):
        print(words[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convertToInt(a):
try:
    num = int(a)
except:
    num = 0
return num

DataWords = [
    "БЕЛЫЙ",
    "Маленький",
    "Хороший",
    "Вредный",
]

myNumbers = input("Enter ").split(" ")
newNumbers = map(convertToInt, myNumbers)

for i,a in enumerate(newNumbers):
    if a in range(0,3):
        print(DataWords[i])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]